# What info do I have to provide when I release a mobile app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, policy, privacy

I'm currently writing an bluetooth app where you can control simple LEDs. Which Information do I have to provide so I can release my app. I mean stuff like Terms of service or privacy policy so that I am doing everything correctly. In my app I need the location (for Android < 12) and the bluetooth. To detect errors, there is also a contact form where you can write a bug and it is sending it to me with the screen resolution, the buildnumber and stuff like that.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this generator](https://termify.io) for app/website policies. You'll also need to have a website to link to with those terms & conditions. You can easily crate and host a website for free using firebase hosting. If you're already using flutter it shouldn't be so hard.